# Mi programa deja de compilar después de un ciclo while c++

Tags: c++

Por alguna razón mi programa deja de compilar después del ciclo while, no importa que le ponga no ejecuta nada después de ese ciclo. Se supone que debe de leer un archivo .txt y guardar los diferentes elementos de ese archivo usando una clase y un constructor.

Me parece que es un problema de memoria pero ya intente de todo, incluso usando pointers pero nada funciona.

Esto es el contenido del archivo:

```
5
Oreo 300 1500
Mantequilla 100 450
Oreo 150 800
Fideo 100 100
Granola 100 240
Gomas 30 120
```

Esta se supone que debería de ser la salida:

```
Oreo 300 1500
Mantequilla 100 450
Oreo 150 800
Fideo 100 100
Granola 100 240
Gomas 30 120
```

Este es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

// Clase comida con sus respectivos sets y gets
class Comida{
    string name;
    int gramos;
    int calorias;
    
    public:
        void set_name(string);
        string get_name(){return name;}
        
        void set_gramos(int);
        int get_gramos(){return gramos;}
        
        void set_calorias(int);
        int get_calorias(){return calorias;}
        
        void Constructor(){
            name = "";
            gramos = 0;
            calorias = 0;
        }       
};

void Comida::set_name(string nombre){name = nombre;}
void Comida::set_gramos(int gr){gramos = gr;}
void Comida::set_calorias(int ca){calorias = ca;}

int main(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string nombre;
    string line;
    int numP;
    string name;
    int gr, cal;
    
    cout<<"Introduce el nombre del archivo (agregue al final \".txt\"): ";
    cin>>nombre;
    
    archivo.open(nombre.c_str(), ios::in);
    
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"Nombre de archivo incorrecto";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        // Lee la primera linea de codigo y la almacena en "line", la cual contiene el numero de elementos a crear
        getline(archivo, line);
    
        // Convierte de string a int
        stringstream degree(line);
        degree>>numP;
    
        Comida productos[numP];
    
        // Contador 
        int count = 0;
    
        while(getline(archivo, line)){

            stringstream ss(line); // Hago un split a mi linea de texto
    
            ss >> name >> gr >> cal; // Guardo los elementos de cada linea en diferentes variables con el split que se le hizo anteriormente
        
            productos[count].Constructor();
            productos[count].set_name(name);
            productos[count].set_gramos(gr);
            productos[count].set_calorias(cal);
        
            count++;
        }
        archivo.close();
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= numP; i++){
            cout<<"\n"<<productos[count].get_name()<<" "<< productos[count].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[count].get_calorias();
        }   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Pero cada vez que lo ejecuto no imprime nada.

Comment: Tu programa no deja de compilar después de un ciclo `while`, tu programa compila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pueden estar sucediendo dos cosas:

1. El programa falla antes de llegar al bucle de impresión.
2. El programa falla antes de descargar los datos a la pantalla.

---

### (1) Primer caso.

En el primer caso el programa fallaría por estar haciendo uso de *Formaciones de Longitud Variable* ([FLV, en inglés *Variable Lenght Array* o VLA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+c%2B%2B+vla)), una característica no estándar que puede provocar errores al usarla y/o porque escribes fuera de tu arreglo.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> necesitan que su tamaño sea conocido en tiempo de compilación, si para definir el tamaño usas una variable en lugar de usar una constante, tienes una FLV y tu programa podría comportarse de manera errática. Ese es tu caso, ya que la formación `productos`:

```
Comida productos[numP];
//               ^^^^ <--- numP es una variable, no una constante.
```

Es una FLV. Además, escribes fuera de la formación pues defines cinco entradas de datos en el archivo pero lees seis:

> ```
> 5                   // Cinco datos
> Oreo 300 1500       // Dato uno
> Mantequilla 100 450 // Dato dos
> Oreo 150 800        // Dato tres
> Fideo 100 100       // Dato cuatro
> Granola 100 240     // Dato cinco
> Gomas 30 120        // Dato ¡oh dios mío! ¡nos hemos pasado de la raya!
> ```

Suponiendo que tu FLV funcione (que no es el caso) escribirías un elemento más de los que has solicitado, provocando un error en tiempo de ejecución.

---

### (2) Segundo caso.

Los flujos de salida de datos no descargan en su flujo inmediatamente, lo hacen al llegar a ciertos límites o cuando se pide explícitamente que lo hagan. Esto sucede así porque la descarga de datos es un proceso costoso y se quiere evitar que este proceso tenga un impacto en el rendimiento del programa.

Esta optimización también provoca que en ocasiones, si el programa falla antes de la descarga en el flujo de datos, parezca que no se ha enviado información al flujo de datos. Para forzar un envío debes usar `flush`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numP; i++){
    cout<<"\n"<<productos[count].get_name()<<" "<< productos[count].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[count].get_calorias();
    cout.flush();
//  ~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Forzar la salida de los datos.
}
```

También puedes usar `std::endl`, que fuerza la salida de los datos y añade un salto de línea:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numP; i++){
    cout<<endl<<productos[count].get_name()<<" "<< productos[count].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[count].get_calorias();
//  ~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Añadir un salto de línea y forzar la salida de los datos.
}
```

---

Una vez explicados tus errores, debo señalar que tu código denota una seria carencia de conocimientos de C++:

1. Los `get` de un objeto deben ser constantes, pues no se espera que modifiquen el estado interno del objeto.
2. El constructor de un objeto debe ser una función sin tipo de retorno que tenga el mismo nombre que el objeto a construir.
3. La lectura de datos se suele hacer sobrecargando el operador de extracción desde flujo de entrada.
4. La escritura de datos se suele hacer sobrecargando el operador de inyección a flujo de salida.
5. No tiene sentido que tu código esté mezclando idiomas, si la clase se llama `Comida` el nombre debería ser `nombre`, o todo en inglés o todo en español.
6. Deja que tu código respire, apretujar el código hace que sea más difícil de leer.

Observa este código equivalente al tuyo, pero escrito en C++ moderno y correcto:

```
class Comida {
    // Inicializamos las variables alli donde se declaran
    string nombre = "";
    int gramos = 0;
    int calorias = 0;
    
public:
    void set_nombre(string nombre) { this->nombre = nombre; }
    string get_nombre() const { return nombre; }
        
    void set_gramos(int gramos) { this->gramos = gramos; }
    int get_gramos() const { return gramos; }
        
    void set_calorias(int calorias) { this->calorias = calorias; }
    int get_calorias() const {return calorias;}

    // Este es el verdadero constructor
    Comida() = default;
};

// Operador de extraccion de datos desde el flujo de entrada
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, Comida &c)
{
    std::string linea;
    if (std::getline(i, linea))
    {
        stringstream ss(linea);

        string name;
        int gr;
        int cal;
        ss >> name >> gr >> cal;
        c.set_nombre(name);
        c.set_gramos(gr);
        c.set_calorias(cal);
    }
    return i;
}

// Operador de inyeccion de datos al flujo de salida
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Comida &c)
{
    return o << c.get_nombre() << " "<< c.get_gramos() << " " << c.get_calorias();
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Comida> productos;

    if (std::ifstream i{"datos"})
    {
        Comida comida;

        while (i >> comida){
            productos.push_back(comida);
        }
    }

    for (const auto &p : productos)
        cout << "\n" << p;

    return 0;
}
```

---

- <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.
- <sup>2</sup>Toda memoria que no se solicita dinámicamente con `new`, es memoria automática.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora entiendo cuales fueron mis errores, gracias por todos tus comentarios. Ahora podré estudiar todo lo que me hizo falta.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código falla en que usas count dentro del bucle donde imprimes:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numP; i++){
    cout<<"\n"<<productos[count].get_name()<<" "<< productos[count].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[count].get_calorias();
}
```

Tendrías que usar el valor de i para recorrer el array y la condición es count que es el número de elementos añadido:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
   cout<<"\n"<<productos[i].get_name()<<" "<< productos[i].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[i].get_calorias();
}
```

Yo además  me crearía una función para contar el número de palabras en la línea, sería así:

```
int countWords(string str)
{ 
    stringstream ss(str);
    string word;

    int count = 0; 
    while (ss >> word) count++; 
    
    return count; 
}
```

De esta forma cuando lees tu fichero puedes ir mirando si la linea contiene 3 elementos, de ser así entonces es una línea válida. La porción del código completo sería así:

```
 Comida productos[numP];
 // Contador 
 int count = 0;

 while(getline(archivo, line)) {
     // Si es una linea de la forma Oreo 300 1500 (con tres palabras)
     // entonces opero sobre ella
     if (countWords(line) == 3)
     {
        stringstream ss(line); // Hago un split a mi linea de texto
        // Guardo los elementos de cada linea en diferentes 
        // variables con el split que se le hizo anteriormente
        ss >> name >> gr >> cal; 
    
        productos[count].Constructor();
        productos[count].set_name(name);
        productos[count].set_gramos(gr);
        productos[count].set_calorias(cal);
    
        count++;
     }
 }
 archivo.close();
 // Imprime resultado   
 for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
     cout<<"\n"<<productos[i].get_name()<<" "<< productos[i].get_gramos()<<" "<<productos[i].get_calorias();
 }
```